# How Can i Drag A JButton Without Creating A Duplicate?

Tags: java, swing, duplicates, jbutton, drag

I'm having trouble with dragging the JButton and not creating a new instance of the button while leaving the old button in place. i drag a JButton with a card face on it and it moves but it just keeps the original one in place.

Comment: To clarify: You want to drag a copy, leaving the original in place? Or you want to drag an image of the original, and move the original when the drag is complete? Or you want to drag the original itself?

Comment: Also, are you using `TransferHandler` for drag and drop? Or custom code of your own?

Comment: issue is somewhere in your code line 457, remove static declaration, now without joking, 
 
for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runable, compilable. demonstrated a.m. issue

Comment: Please have a look at [DragLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) by @camickr, I hope this might will interest you :-)